# Make input variables inactive when computing the jacobian

Tags: openmdao

## Make input variables inactive when computing the jacobian

We are setting up an aero elastic optimization framework for wind turbine optimization and we are there facing issues with defining inputs and outputs for the components.

The issues is that we might have many inputs and outputs for a solver (example further down) but they are likely not active for all optimization cases. It leads to the problem that we need to compute partials for all combinations of input and output even though we only might have a single input and output. Is it possible to tell the component which input and outputs are active design variables?

**Example:**
An aerodynamic wind turbine rotor solver (ExplicitComponent).

*Inputs*

- Chord (*c*, distributed along the blade span - 1D array)
- Twist (*t*, distributed along the blade span - 1D array)

*Outputs*

- Power (*P*, scalar)
- Lift coefficient (*Cl*, distributed along the blade span - 1D array)

For the solver above we have both AD forward and backward gradients. Below we have two optimization problems where the fist do not lead to computational overhed but the other does.

*Optimization problem 1*
Maximize power while constraining the lift-coefficient to 1

```
max P for c, t
subj Cl <= 1
```

All input and outputs are active design-variables and objectives/constraints.

*Optimization problem 2*
Maximize power

```
max P for c, t
```

If using the same OpenMDAO component the *Cl* output is still there and it would therefore compute the gradient for it. But that is computational expensive as all the needed gradient are given when running reverse AD for *P*, but it will still to compute the gradients for *Cl*. Is there is a way to side step that behavior? Ex. making the output inactive?

We have tried to make input and output dynamic for the component but it quickly get to be difficult code to read and for nested components is difficult to keep. Another thing is that it is mostly a think you need to define for the *problem* and not the *component*.

Comment: It sounds like you've already done this, but way I've typically dealt with this is to make an option on your component that allows you to specify whether gradients are needed.

Another possibility is to use the component's matrix-free derivative API as described here:  https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/features/core_features/working_with_components/explicit_component.html#the-matrix-free-api-providing-derivatives-as-a-matrix-vector-product

Answer (score 1):

You mention that you are using AD, but not which of the derivative APIs you are using. From the context of your question it sounds like you're using the `compute_partials` API. That means you're likely asking the AD system to compute all the partials you need and then passing them to OpenMDAO.

Assuming that I have guessed right, then there is one possible way to speed things up a bit here and get the effects you are looking for without explicitly turning I/O on an off, and AD based partials are particularly well suited to this approach.

The matrix-free derivative APIs in OpenMDAO are designed to give you the exact behavior you want automatically. For ExplicitComponent, the method is called [`compute_jacvec_product`](http://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/3.21.0/features/core_features/working_with_components/explicit_component.html#the-matrix-free-api-providing-derivatives-as-a-matrix-vector-product). In the example from the OpenMDAO docs, this is implemented manually but it should tie in with an AD system very easily. For example the JAX AD library has [JVP](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.jvp.html#jax.jvp) and ['VJP`][3] methods that can be used in the` fwd`an`rev` modes of the OpenMDAO matrix-free APIs respectively.

When using these Matrix-free APIs, OpenMDAO will only call your AD system a minimum number of times. The exact number depends on if OpenMDAO selects `fwd` or `rev` mode (or what you hard code in setup) and then also on the number of design variables, and constraints you have.

In your case, I would guess you'd end up using reverse mode. Then when you don't have the CL constraint, you wouldn't get the extra calls to the AD library.

There are a few additional caveats for the matrix-free APIs when using implicit components that I didn't cover here. Your question specifically noted ExplicitComponent, so Im not sure they are relevant. But I wanted to note that if you graduate to implicit components then you have to worry about the `solve_linear` method along with the `apply_linear` (which is the Implicit analogue to the `compute_jacvec_product` explicit method)